# MySQL event scheduler doesn't work

Tags: mysql, errors, jobs, event

I have the following MySQL event sheduler to udpate some values in RECETAS table's ESTADO column. I want to run it everyday at 10:05:00.

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS actualizar_prueba
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS '2014-09-23 10:05:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE 
  DO
    UPDATE precetas.RECETAS
    SET ESTADO = 1
    WHERE ESTADO = 3;
```

This is what is shown when I run the SHOW events\G command. It seems that it is executed only once (Type) and with no Interval value. But if I change EVERY 1 DAY and I write EVERY 1 MINUTE the event is executed every minute, then could someone tell my what does Type and Interval value mean? Is the event created well?

```
                  Db: precetas
                Name: test_event_01
             Definer: root@localhost
           Time zone: SYSTEM
                **Type: ONE TIME**
          Execute at: 2014-09-23 10:54:56
      **Interval value: NULL**
      Interval field: NULL
              Starts: NULL
                Ends: NULL
              Status: ENABLED
          Originator: 0
character_set_client: utf8
collation_connection: utf8_general_ci
  Database Collation: utf8_general_ci
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a guess,maybe there is nothign to update the second day?